# What is the best way to make conditional logic for three field check

Tags: javascript, loops

I have 3 listbox which are related one another. Each listbox populate to next listbox values. I would like to get selected values then post by ajax request to server.

User might select only LIST A or LIST A and LIST B or all LISTBOX value. The important thing is url might change each selected value. Therefore, I want to write conditional logic based on these values. I know, I can use nested `if`'s but I want to learn more appropiate method.

```
+------------------------+-----+
| LISTBOX A              | --- |
+------------------------+-----+

+------------------------+-----+
| LISTBOX B              | --- |
+------------------------+-----+   

+------------------------+-----+
| LISTBOX C              | --- |
+------------------------+-----+

// Pseudo Code
IF A SELECTED 
   POST ONLY VALUE A
IF A AND B SELECTED
   POST VALUE A AND VALUE B
IF A, B AND C SELECTED
   POST VALUE A, VALUE B, VALUE C
```

I am using ExtJS framework, here is the listbox definitions.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'ANA MAL GRUBU',
    store: articleMain,
    id: 'art-main-group',
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoSelect: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    inputWidth: 240,
    margin: '5 0 0 0',
    listConfig: { cls: 'combo-dep' },
    valueField: 'PWHG',
    displayField: 'PWHG_BEZ',
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo) {
            articleBase.proxy.extraParams = {'maingroup': combo.getValue(), type: 'article_base'};
            articleBase.load();
        }
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'MAL GRUBU',
    store: articleBase,
    id: 'art-base-group',
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoSelect: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'PWG',
    displayField: 'PWG_BEZ',
    inputWidth: 240,
    margin: '10 0 0 0',
    listConfig: { cls: 'combo-dep' },
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo) {
            articleSub.proxy.extraParams = {'maingroup': Ext.getCmp('art-main-group').getValue(), 'basegroup': combo.getValue(), 'type': 'article_sub'}
            articleSub.load();
        }
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'ALT MAL GRUBU',
    store: articleSub,
    id: 'art-sub-group',
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoSelect: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'PWUG',
    displayField: 'PWUG_BEZ',
    inputWidth: 240,
    margin: '10 0 0 0',
    listConfig: { cls: 'combo-dep' }
},
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'SEÇİLEN MAL GRUBU',
    id: 'art-status',
    width: 300,
    margin: '10 0 0 0',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            boxLabel: 'DAHİL',
            name: 'artstatus',
            inputValue: 'INCLUDE'
        },
        {
            boxLabel: 'HARİÇ',
            name: 'artstatus',
            inputValue: 'EXCLUDE',
            margin: '0 0 0 20'
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        change: function(radio, newValue) {
            console.log(newValue.artstatus);
        }
    }
}
```

]
},

Comment: What does the HTML currently look like? We can't really give you a answer that will help without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Why dont u just use else if`s?

Comment: Dear @Hoff as I said, I can use but I was curious is there any more appropiate way.

Comment: @George Stocker what have to do HTML with logic? I think the op was specific enough about the question, it was not any need for him to edit it and it and editing it is just adding confusion.

Comment: @JuanGarcia Without seeing the list of elements to manipulate, it's hard for us to give him an end-to-end solution.

Comment: @George Stocker I don't agree, it is a logic question, the element names doesn't matter at all for what he is asking, that why he was using pseudo code in here. A, B and C and it relation is enough to understand the question and give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
if(x = (a && ((b && ((c && 3) || 2)) || 1))) doStuff(x) ;
```

x will be 1 if a is true and b is false whichever c is, will be 2 if a and b is true but c false and 3 if all of them are true, or false if a is false whichever b or c are.

Comment: definitely seems harder to follow than if statements.

Comment: @George Stocker I agree, the only advantage it is probably character length saving

Comment: _Character length saving_, before minification, is __never__ an advantage. The readability cost will always outweigh the "savings."

Comment: @Mathletics you are probably right, however I don't fully trust the minifier in a case like this. And in some situations you may have many nested if that can't be replace by a switch statement, if you get used to this kind of syntax it can be even more readable, as you can get a picture of the whole thing without having to scroll over the screen.

Comment: This is the kind of "cute" JS that makes other developers (and you, 6 months after you last looked at this code) go WHAT THE ACTUAL F@#$ and pull your hair out. Scrolling is not the enemy!

Comment: @Mathletics I used to have that "write only" problems before, and that is not JS exclusive. Now I can use funny syntax and come back 1 year after and read the code and know what is about. The difference is how I name my variables, I never use short name by exception of i in for loops or e for exceptions, for the answer I did it to match the question. One more thing is and don't mix calculations within expresions, if something deserves to have it's own variable, it will. For me it is so much more simple and self explained an expresion like this that a brunch of cascade jquery methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your all suggestions. As a result, code readability in a fact that I did as follows ( no chance to use another thing except if condition ).

PS : I changed reverse order of the if clause so that last condition being first.

```
    // LIST C equal to sub_group, LIST B equal to base_group
    handler: function() {
    var main_group, base_group, sub_group;
    if (Ext.getCmp('art-sub-group').getValue() != null) {
        main_group = Ext.getCmp('art-main-group').getValue();
        base_group = Ext.getCmp('art-base-group').getValue();
        sub_group = Ext.getCmp('art-sub-group').getValue();
    } else if (Ext.getCmp('art-main-group').getValue() != null && Ext.getCmp('art-base-group').getValue() != null) {
        base_group = Ext.getCmp('art-base-group').getValue();
        main_group = Ext.getCmp('art-main-group').getValue();
    } else {
        main_group = Ext.getCmp('art-main-group').getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, testing `main` **and** `base` on the second if would imply that you should test all three on the first if too. If not, I think only testing for `base` only should be enough (on the second condition). Meaning the current logic starts with *"if the last element is set, all previous should be set"*, so why not continue that thought on the following condition?

Comment: Dear Yoshi, all listbox conditional, means user should first select something from first listbox then second listbox populated based on the first listbox value. Therefore, user can't select last or second listbox without first.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. But the condition on the second if implies that the user could do otherwise. I think, you could simplify it to: `} else if (Ext.getCmp('art-base-group').getValue() != null) {` and thus following the same logic from the first condition.